# How to require the proper version of test/unit

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

I'm trying to require the new (i.e. not the one bundled with ruby) version of `test/unit`. As per the [instructions](http://test-unit.rubyforge.org/) I installed it with `gem i test-unit`. But now when I require `test/unit` I seem to be requiring the old version. For example, I don't have the method `Test::Unit.at_start`. This happens even when I explicitly require the full path to the new `test/unit` installation.

Is there any way for me to investigate which symbols are being loaded and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Ruby comes with an implementation of `test/unit` (it’s actually a Minitest compatibility wrapper) calling `require 'test/unit'` will load that version, since it is already on the load path. Calling `require '/absolute/path/to/test/unit'` will load the new file, but when that file calls e.g. `require 'test/unit/testcase` it will load the files from stdlib, resulting in a mix of classes (so don’t do that).

What you need to do is activate the gem with the [`gem` method](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Kernel.html#method-i-gem) before you `require` it. That will ensure the gem lib path is on your load path *before* the stdlib, so `require` will find those files first.

```
gem 'test-unit'     # You can also pass a specific version as a second
                    # argument to `gem` if you want.

require 'test/unit' # This will find the gem version.

# Now the gem version will be loaded.
```

Comment: Thanks. But is this the proper way to do it? Seems kind of hackish. Shouldn't the author have provided something more elegant?

Comment: @Johnny you need to say “use the gem version of `test/unit` not the stdlib version”. The `gem` method is how you do that. You don’t normally need to use `gem` since there usually isn’t a clash of names, but when there is you need it. You could also use Bundler, which is basically doing the same thing (activating the gems you specify so they are used in preference to stdlib). I did notice that the gem has a `test-unit` file (notice the `-` instead of `/`) which the stdlib doesn’t have, but I don’t know the difference between using that and `test/unit`.